# linux centos 7 не завершает работу

Tags: linux, centos

После нажатия выключения или команды shutdown и shotdown now, появляется чёрный экран с изображенными в хаотичном порядке процессами или [ok] а в конце написано power off
[какие-то цифры] power down и н аэтом моменте дальше ничего не происходит,
пробовал в system.conf stoptimeout ставить на 10сек, но это не помогло...

на данный момент выключить можно только зажатием кнопки питания...

Comment: Команда `shutdown` или `shutdown -h now` ?

Comment: shutdown, shutdown now

Comment: попробуйте `shutdown -h now`

Comment: спасибо, так работает! а есть идеи как разобраться с причинами такого поведения? ведь я так понимаю shutdown -h now это alias for halt, а это вроде не очень корректная остановка работы..

Comment: **как разобраться с причинами такого поведения?**  - сталкивался с аналогичной проблемой. Причина заключалось в том, что был смонтирован NFS  раздел (сетевой), а в момент попытки задаунить хост, сервер с этим разделом был недоступен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shutdown -h now
```

`halt` - останавливает все процессы ЦП.
Конбинация этих команд включает Комп.

[Тут можно прочесть](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205465/156515)

Comment: я так понимаю, что все дело в каком-то процессе, но как понять какой именно?

Comment: @Artyom если это помогло, нажмите на галочку принять ответ. Если есть другие вопросы надавайте. Может еще кому-нибудь поможете разобраться.